# Estimate word-metric length in free nilpotent groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory

I would like to estimate the length of a word in a free nilpotent group. As the first example, I would like to estimate the word metric in the Heisenberg group $H_3$. This is the group of upper triangulate matrices with integer entries and ones on the diagonal. In this particular case, we generate the Heisenberg group by the matrices $\mathrm{Id}_3 + e_{1,2}$ and $\mathrm{Id}_3+ e_{2,1}$. The word length of an element is the number of generators employed to write the element in the shortest possible form.
I found the following in a beamer presentation of Pansu ([https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~pansu/oxford13nov10_beamer.pdf](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Epansu/oxford13nov10_beamer.pdf), page 4):

> Heisenberg group in its Carnot-Carathéodory metric gives a sharp approximation of the word metric on the integral Heisenberg group

(the integral  Heisenberg group is what I defined as Heisenberg group above). However, I could not find a reference for the sharp approximation (and I don't know about Carnot-Carathéodory metrics, so any reference of this topic is welcome). Also, I am new to the length metric and related topics, so I don't know if there is a closed formula for the length which is unknown to me.

For example:
As a general problem, note that any element in a nilpotent group of class $c$ with $n$ generators $a_1,\dots, a_n$ can be written as
$$a_1^{r_1}a_2^{r_2}\dots a_n^{r_n} c$$
where $c$ belongs to the cartesian subgroup (that is, the kernel of the canonical quotient $F_n \to \mathbb{Z}^n$, where $F_n$ is the free group in n letters). Moreover, it is possible to be more explicit in the writing of $c$.

Is there a known way to give bounds to the length of the word metric for every word of this form?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The word length can be estimated using the Guivarch length of the logarithm of the element in the Lie algebra. In the form you provide, the whole point is to be more explicit on the element $c$ of the derived subgroup.

Comment: Thank tou very much for youy reply. Could you mention some bibliography about these topics? I cannot find especific text and closed formulas of the distance in the discrete case (also, I don't know how explicit can be built this kind of formulas). Again, thank you for your reply.

Comment: https://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/carnot_caratheodory.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!